# How to skip specific cycle loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx, cycle

I would like to create such a Shape.

[image]

Just draw a [Circle](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Circle.html) and then [Lines](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Line.html).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SkipPartsOfCycle extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(new Circle(500, 500, 100, Color.GREEN));
        drawLine(pane, 0, 20, 5);
        drawLine(pane, 70, 110, 5);
        drawLine(pane, 160, 200, 5);
        drawLine(pane, 250, 290, 5);
        drawLine(pane, 340, 360, 5);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 1000, 1000));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void drawLine (Pane pane, int start, int end, int increment) {
        for (var i = start; i <= end; i += increment) {
            pane.getChildren().add(new Line(500,500, 500 + (100 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i))), 500 + (100 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)))));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This code works. The problem is that to skip specific parts of a cycle, I call it several times with a specific range. Another solution is to insert the condition into the cycle, but it would be unnecessarily complicated.

The biggest problem is that since I call it several times, when changing (eg 0-30,60-120,150-210,240-300,330-360) it is necessary to modify all method calls and not just one.

Is there a simpler solution, please?

Comment: The ‘continue’ keyword is your friend.

Comment: work through a tutorial on java language basics to learn how to code conditionals and how to refactor stuff appropriately - nothing special fx here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can boil your problem down to drawing lines whenever the steps of your loop fall within 20 degrees before or after angles measuring 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees, so some branching logic should let you draw your figure with a single pass.

In truth, creating a method and calling it five times isn't a big deal in terms of overhead, not to mention making your code somewhat more flexible, so your solution isn't actually bad.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 360; i += 5) {
            if((i <= 20) || 
              (i >= 70 && i <= 110) ||
              (i >= 160 && i <= 200) ||
              (i >= 250 && i <= 290)
              (i >= 340))
            {
                pane.getChildren().add(new Line(500,500, 500 + (100 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i))), 500 + (100 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)))));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I misspelled the question and didn't say the main thing. This way can be used, but I immediately rejected it, because the result is that it is necessary to evaluate several hundred conditions. However, I forgot to mention that when changing (eg 0-30,60-120,150-210,240-300,330-360), it is necessary to modify all method calls. And that is the main problem.

Comment: factor it out: create a class/method that draws n lines in m intervals, then keep some list of n/m pairs and walk it to message the class/method

Comment: @MichalRama What do you mean by "modify all method calls?" You mean you expect a method to respond to changing conditions using the same parameters?

Comment: @MarsAtomic Of course, that won't change on its own. All I want to do is make the values ​​easy to change.

Comment: @MichelRama I see. What about packaging the drawing loop into a method and adding parameters for the "base angle" that anchors your drawing and an offset before the base angle and an offset after the base angle, along with the other parameters from the method you call five times. That base angle arg would be 90, offset1 is 20, offset2 is 20 and you can just modify my branching logic to use the args instead of having hardcoded magic numbers. Let me know if this is clear. If not, I can just edit the code.